# How do I use cubes or tiles to form the outside of my 3D HTML5 sphere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, 3d, html5-canvas

I want to build a UI that is a three dimensional sphere. It is able to rotate and scroll in and out. I have posted a sphere here that I was hoping to use: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/vbvfnxxz/

```
<div id="rootDiv">
    <!-- Main Canvas -->
    <canvas id="renderCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is what I want to do with this sphere. I want to make it more interactive. Specifically, I want to make cubes or square tiles form the outside of the sphere, like these images:

http://www.123rf.com/photo_10160495_a-sphere-made-up-of-tiles-featuring-question-marks-symbolizing-a-world-of-confusion-or-curiosity-and.html

http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-photos-sphere-made-small-cubes-image11662558

I wanted to give you my overall vision. Ideally, I would have a sphere that is made of cubes/tiles and you can rollover those cubes. Each cube has an icon of an application. Once one of the cubes is rolled over it expands out much larger so you can see the description of the application. I can then click on the cube to go to a page for that application.

I know this kind of UI design is probably really difficult and probably not done often or at all. And I can’t use Flash unfortunately. But I can use jQuery, JavaScript, and HTML5.  I figured since you can make elaborate video games in HTML5, it should be able to handle this. So my question is how do I use cubes/tiles to form the outside of my 3D sphere? Any direction would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Try using `css` `transform:matrix()`